# Ubuntu 18.04 upgrade stuck on splash screen

Tags: boot, dual-boot, upgrade, 18.04

Just did an upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04 from 16.04 and i am getting stuck on the splash screen.

Right now i have turned off quiet splash and found that I am getting stuck on:

"Started Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes". It hangs here while the screen flickers off and on.